# Counting number of perfect matching in bipartite graph.

Tags: combinatorics, graphing-functions

Graph G is bipartite graph, I want to just count number of perfect matching.
Is there any algorithm exist using combinatorial+graph theory, by which i cant count this.
I tried by traversing the graph, but as there are so many possibilities and I just want number of perfect matching I asked here.

Comment: Some information at http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19924/counting-and-finding-all-perfect-maximum-matchings-in-general-graphs also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/131279/how-many-perfect-matchings-in-a-regular-bipartite-graph Type $$\rm number\ of\ perfect\ matchings\ in\ a\ bipartite\ graph$$ into Google and see what else you get.

Comment: The first thing to note is that [there may not be any](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall's_marriage_theorem).  The number of perfect matchings in a bipartite graph will depend on the graph, and you've not suggested how the graph (nodes+edges) is going to be specified.  Perhaps you have a simple case in mind, like the number of perfect matchings in a *complete* bipartite graph?