# counting full bipartite matchings

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, permanent

My actual question is to find the number of transversal given a collection of set ...

After a little bit of study it has come down to:

How can we count the number of matchings in a bipartite graph with parts of size $m$ and $n$ such that it covers all $m$ vertices of the first part, $m \le n$?

I already know that there is a way to count the number of perfect matchings in a bipartite graph with $m=n$ using the permanent of its (square) incidence matrix.

Comment: Your notation implies the bipartite graph is a "complete" one, $K_{m,n}$.  Is this the intent?  @GerryMyerson's references in this other [recent Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/885498/3111) may be of interest.

Comment: but I am not interested in counting perfect matching...btw the graph is not a complete one either

Comment: I understand you are not interested in perfect matchings, but by saying "it covers all $m$ vertices," you apparently intend to count maximum matchings, and this is covered by [Algorithms for Enumerating All Perfect, Maximum and
Maximal Matchings in Bipartite Graphs](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.107.8179&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: thanks..but this document provides a way of enumerating all maximum matching....but I am more interested to know the technique of counting the number of maximum matching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given an *arbitrary* bipartite graph $G$ with parts $A,B$ such that $|A|=m \le n = |B|$, the number $M$ of matchings that cover all $m$ vertices in $A$ can be expressed by a summation of $\binom{n}{m}$ permanents:

$$ M = \sum_{R\in \mathcal{S}} \operatorname{perm} I_R $$

where the summation is taken over all the incidence matrices $I_R$ for subgraphs $G \cap (A\times R)$ resulting from choosing any $m$-subset $R \subset B$:

$$ \mathcal{S} = \{ R \subset B : |R| = m \} $$

Note that in the generality posed in the Question, there is [no guarantee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_marriage_theorem) that any of these summands will be nonzero.  The computation of (binary) [permanents is $\#P$-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_is_sharp-P-complete), so in most cases these will be difficult computations to perform with large $m,n$.

Comment: thanks...i cant vote up..dont have 15 reputation

Comment: In my case n=100,m=10, can you give me an efficient technique of perm calculation , so that for above constraint I can calculate it within 1sec? For the naive method 100C10 is order of 10^13 which is not going to work here

Comment: How to efficiently compute a $10\times 10$ permanent of an incidence matrix seems like it should be posted as a separate Question.  The paper I linked to originally addresses efficiency more comprehensively than this format allows.  Out of curiosity, is there information about degree sequences or # of edges?