# Counting all Perfect Matchings in arbitrary graph

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, matching-theory

Counting the number of [perfect matchings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)) in a [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) is known to be difficult, actually [#P complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-complete) (see a nice [math.SE question+answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890343/counting-full-bipartite-matchings)).

I was wondering what is known for other graphs? For instance, it is known that for complete graphs, the number of perfect matchings goes [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

- Are there graphs where counting all perfect matchings is simple aswell?
- Are there graphs where counting all perfect matchings is even more difficult than for bipartite graphs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counting perfect matchings in an arbitrary graph is definitely in #P: it corresponds to the "Does this graph have a perfect matching?" problem, which is in NP because we can efficiently check that a set of edges is a perfect matching. So the problem can't get any more difficult than #P-complete for any class of graphs.

I wouldn't say that counting perfect matchings in a complete graph really fits into this framework; it's not a very large class of graphs, is it? We can write down a formula for the number of perfect matchings in a complete graph. There's also a [well-known formula](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196885801907523) for the number of domino tilings of an $m \times n$ chessboard: $$T(m,n) = \prod_{j=1}^m \prod_{k=1}^n \sqrt{4 \cos^2 \frac{j\pi}{m+1} + 4 \cos^2 \frac{k \pi}{n+1}}.$$ This, of course, is also the number of perfect matchings in an $m \times n$ grid graph.

We do have larger classes of graphs for which the problem is easy (polynomial-time algorithms exist).

- Planar graphs;
- More generally, graphs of bounded [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Graph_theory);
- Graphs of bounded [treewidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth).

([Okamoto, Uehara, Uno 2009](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8e65/d2da352d2a7cba81a09ec30418c9d598ca22.pdf)) provide citations for the examples above, and find polynomial-time algorithms for several other classes of graphs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, in particular for the reference, that was what I was hoping for.