# Number of perfect matchings in a $K_{m,n}$ bipartite graph?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

How would you find the number of perfect matchings of a $K_{m,n}$ bipartite graph?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos My question is in relation to Bipartite graphs. The link you gave is in realtion to complete graphs.

Comment: [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890343/counting-full-bipartite-matchings), on the other hand, seems like it may fit better.

Comment: What can you say about $m$ and $n$ for a perfect matching to even exist? In the case they exist, can you make further progress?